# How to pad a text with custom length after build the vocab in pytorch

Tags: padding, vocabulary, torchtext

I used torchtext vocab to convert the text to index

For example 1 have 2 names
`aaban aabharan`

After vocab:
`[0, 0, 1, 0, 2] [0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0, 2]`

Since the length of longest name in my data is 24
After using
`torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([torch.tensor(name) for name in name], batch_first=True, padding_value = -1.)`

I got
`tensor([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]) tensor([ 0,  0,  1,  3,  0,  4,  0,  2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])`

But i want to create the tensors with length 50, as there might be longer names which might not be in training data, how can i do it
As in, how can i get the following,
`tensor([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]) tensor([ 0,  0,  1,  3,  0,  4,  0,  2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,-1, -1, -1, -1 ])`

I tried going through the dcoumentation for both tochtext.vocab and orch.nn.utils but i couldn't find a way